# Call server_name in img src correctly

Tags: php, html

trying to get my head around if I can call the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in an `img` `src` somehow on a PHP page. I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
<?php 
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$dir = '/content/images/';
?>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<img src="<? echo 'https://',$domain,$dir,'logo.png' ; ?>">

Alternatively (if possible)
<img src="<? echo 'https://',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],$dir,'logo.png' ; ?>">

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched around and tried different ways but can't seem to get it right. 
Is it possible?

Comment: `$dir` shouldn't contain the filename.

Comment: You're creating a URL like `/content/images/favicon.pnglogo.png`

Comment: The server name part is fine.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, had copied and pasted and forgot to remove the file name in $dir. 

I have edited the dir and tried the following:
`<img src="<? echo 'https://',$domain,$dir,'logo.png' ; ?>">`

Image comes up as broken (should show image from ie. "https://serverdomainname.com/content/images/logo.png").

Comment: Edit the question, show what you expect to get and what you're getting instead.

Comment: Thanks Barmar - stepped away and went for a walk and came back with fresh eyes! Adjusted my test file on fresh and now it works just fine, something must have been missing! Thanks for your input!